# How is the Tx/Rx Gain calculated in USRP?

Tags: antenna, gain, transmitter, receiver, sdr

I'm using Software Defined Radio NI USRP 2922 (Universal Software Radio Peripheral). I know that USRPs are uncalibrated devices. In many exampls you can set the so called Tx or Rx gain (as in the picture below).

[image]

Now, I know that this does not correspond to the real power of the transmitter, nor is it a "gain" of the antenna - the most appropriate term here would be "transmitter channel gain", right?

So I would like to know how this transmitter channel gain process is implemented, how it is calculated, and how it works in practice (since a particular gain value doesn't correspond to a particular power level).

Comment: Electrical engineering is a very broad field. Therefore you should define acronyms that are not common. This category would include USRP. Thank you.,

Comment: I edited my post. USRP is software defined radio from National Instruments. My model is NI USRP 2922.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set gain (attenuation) in hardware.

NI USRP 2922 is basically [N210 + SBX](https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA03q000000wwacCAA&l=en-US) from Ettus research. From their [pages](https://www.ettus.com/all-products/un210-kit/) and [knowledgebase](https://kb.ettus.com/SBX) you can get better description (and schematics) than NI provides. In knowledgebase is mentioned that used dautherboard (SBX) use [HMC624LP4E](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Analog%20Devices%20PDFs/HMC624LP4E.pdf) attenuator.

Just to be sure, [NI USRP 2922](https://www.ni.com/documentation/en/usrp-software-defined-radio-device/latest/specs-usrp-2922/specs/) specifications have exactly same gain range and step as does the mentioned attenuator.